# Cannot compile lib_mysqludf_sys for mariadb

Tags: database, mariadb

I'm trying to create a lib_mysqludf_sys.so for mariadb database but everytime when I run it there is an error. Does anyone know how to fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mitpb.png)

┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/OSCP/sandbox/lib_mysqludf_sys]
└─$ make
gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/mariadb/server -I/usr/include/mariadb/ -I/usr/include/mariadb/server/private -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o lib_mysqludf_sys.so
In file included from lib_mysqludf_sys.c:40:
/usr/include/mariadb/my_global.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
3 | #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
|  ^~~~~~~
In file included from lib_mysqludf_sys.c:41:
/usr/include/mariadb/my_sys.h:3:2: warning: #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h> [-Wcpp]
3 | #warning This file should not be included by clients, include only <mysql.h>
|  ^~~~~~~
lib_mysqludf_sys.c:44:10: fatal error: m_ctype.h: No such file or directory
44 | #include <m_ctype.h>
|          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:4: install] Error 1

Comment: `m_ctype.h` should be in /usr/include/mariadb. What version of MariaDB devel package do you have?.

Answer (score 0):

This udf project is nowadays more than a decade of years old. Files were renamed or removed, so now wonder why the build fails. And it was initially written for MySQL, not for MariaDB.

I would recommend to check the [udf_example.c](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/11.0/sql/udf_example.c) code in MariaDB server and to fix the include files. I would also recommend to define STANDARD when building the shared object (-DSTANDARD).